# Need assistance understanding a shift calculation and trimming some fat off my code

Tags: c++, for-loop, encryption

I was going over this code to read a file on my desktop that decrypts a cesar cipher code and I am stuck trying to figure out how the shift is calculated in this program.

From what I can tell, Max e's is the shifted letter with the highest frequency. Since e's are the most common letter in English, the program is trying to set the highest frequency char in the cipher, to an 'e' in English. Which is good, as far as it goes, but there are many phrases where e's are NOT the most frequent letter, and then it will fall on it's face.

So, how can I tell the program to guess at the most frequent cipher letter to be an e in plain text BUT in case it isn't, then proceed to try an e shifted to the second most frequent letter in the text, and so on, until I find it?

A friend helped with that part but has poor English so it is difficult for him to explain it to me. Can someone please elaborate? Assistance is greatly appreciated! Let me know what you think:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype> // isalpha, islower, isupper, functions
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string caesarShift(string text, int shift);
int main()
{
    int maxEs = 0;       // # of e's in maxString
    int currentEs = 0;    // # of e'sin currentString
    string maxString;       // decrypted caesar shift with most e's
    string currentString;    //decrypted caesar shift

    string cipher;       // Stores cipher text
    char ch;    // Stores currentcharacter for reading
    ifstream fin("/Users/jasonrodriguez/Desktop/encrypted.txt");   //opens "encrypted.txt" file
    while( fin.get(ch) )    // readseach char into the cipher till EOF
    {
        cipher += ch;
    }
    fin.close();    // be safe andclose file

    for(int i=0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        currentEs =0;    // Reset counter
        currentString =caesarShift(cipher, i);    // get shifted text
        for(unsigned int x=0; x <currentString.size(); x++) // check each character of stringarray
        {
            if(currentString[x] == 'e' || currentString[x] == 'E') // check fore's
            {
                currentEs++;    // increment Ecounter
            }
        }
        if(currentEs > maxEs) //if currentEs is greater than maxEs, replace max with current
        {
            maxEs =currentEs;
            maxString= currentString;
        }
    }
    cout << maxString << endl;
    return 0;
}

/**
 string caesarShift(string text, int shift)
 Decrypts Caesar Shift using text and shift
 */
string caesarShift(string text, int shift)
{
    shift = shift % 26;    // Morethan 26 is redundant and unneeded
    char ch = 0; // holds current character
    char chs = 0;    // holds shiftedcharacter
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < text.size();i++)
    {
        ch = text[i];
        if( isalpha(ch) )
        {
            chs = ch -shift; // reverse shifting
            if( (islower(ch) && chs < 'a' )  // If is lowercase andshifted value is lower than 'a'
               ||
               ( isupper(ch) && chs < 'A' ) ) // Ifis uppercase and shifted value is lower than 'A'
            {
                chs += 26;    // Add 26(number ofletters) to get back to the correct place in alphabet
            }
            text[i] =chs;    // Set character to shifted character
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

**Questions:**

1. From what I can tell, Max e's is the shifted letter with the highest frequency. Since e's are the most common letter in English, the program is trying to set the highest frequency char in the cipher, to an 'e' in English. Which is good, as far as it goes, but there are many phrases where e's are NOT the most frequent letter, and then it will fall on it's face. So, how can I tell the program to guess at the most frequent cipher letter to be an e in plain text BUT in case it isn't, then proceed to try an e shifted to the second most frequent letter in the text, and so on, until I find it?
2. I think if I shift a character by a shift amount the character may or may not be out of bounds. 'a' + 3 is 'd' ok, 'x' + 3 is '{' not ok. So if the character is over 'z' take away 26, if under 'a' add 26. can be a usable function. However, can you please explain to me how the shift is calculated in the program and is applied it to the file? It has me totally stumped :(

Comment: How do you keep track of the letter frequencies and the corresponding shift?

Comment: That is a big part of my question yes

Comment: I suggest that you start by looking at std::map. You can use it to store the frequencies.

Comment: I think if I shift a character by a shift amount the character may or may not be out of bounds. 

'a' + 3 is 'd'  ok,
'x' + 3 is '{'  not ok. 

So if the character is over 'z' take away 26, if under 'a' add 26. can be a usable function. However, can you please explain to me how the shift is calculated in the program and is applied it to the file? It has me totally stumped :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Calculating a shift:**

First, you need to mapy the letters 'A' through 'Z' (assuming only uppercase letters) to the integers 0 through 25. C++ let's you do this easily with subtraction:

```
n = c - 'A';
```

Now you can perform the shift with modulus arithmetic:

```
n = (n + shift) % 26;
```

Finally map back to a letter:

```
p = n + 'A';
```

(Note that you will need apprporiate declarations for the variables used in these examples. I suggest that you use more meaningful names than the single-letter variables names I use.)